# Distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ if $X_1\pm X_2$ are two independent $N(1,4)$

Tags: probability-theory

$X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2 $ are *i.i.d.* $N(1,4)$. What is the distribution of $X = (X_1,X_2)^T$?

I know *i.i.d.* is an independent and identically distributed random variable but I don't know how to use it to solve this problem that contains a column vector.

Comment: What does this have to do with computer science?

Comment: Are you familiar with multivariate normal distributions?

Comment: Please don't roll back edits that others make to your question.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/editing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y = (Y_1,Y_2)$ be two i.i.d. $N(1,4)$ variables. Then $Y$ is a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), and so any [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) of $Y$ is a multivariate normal distribution. In particular, if we define $X_1 = \frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{2}$ and $X_2 = \frac{Y_1 - Y_2}{2}$ then $X = (X_1,X_2)$ is a multivariate normal distribution which satisfies $X_1 + X_2 = Y_1$ and $X_1 - X_2 = Y_2$. In other words, it is the random variable you're interested in.

It is routine to calculate
$$
(X_1,X_2) \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\right),
$$
that is, $X_1 \sim N(1,2)$ and $X_2 \sim N(0,2)$, and $X_1,X_2$ are independent.